# grep everything up until and including a pattern

Tags: awk, sed, grep, gnu

Let's assume I have a log file that contains exceptions as shown

```
java.lang.NullPointerException blabla
ABC.Exception blalabbla
dogchacecat.Exception yadayada
```

I want to be able to output each line from beginning and up until (including) "Exception"

desired output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
ABC.Exception
dogchacecat.Exception
```

How do I do this using any GNU tool (grep, awk, sed)?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -o '.*Exception' file
```

**-o, --only-matching**
             *Prints only the matching part of the lines.*

`'.*Exception'`
This will match between 0 and unlimited occurrences of any character (except for line terminators) up until the word "Exception"

---

In order to get the behavior you mentioned in the comment (pull the string before and including `Exception` up until any leading whitespace) you can use extended or perl regex to use the `\S` control character (any non-whitespace character):

```
grep -oE '\S+Exception' file
```

Comment: What if I want to print only the contiguous non-empty sequence of words, chars or dots that come before ".Exception"? so that when I have input as:

bla bla bla java.lang.NullPointerException yada yada yada

it only prints:
java.lang.NullPointerException

Thanks @Jesse_b

Comment: @abadawi: That should be an edit to your question or possibly even a new question altogether but I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That's exactly the behavior I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

With POSIX utilities (so will work with GNU and non-GNU implementations):

everything up to the *first* occurrence of `Exception` on a line:

```
sed -n 's/\(Exception\).*/\1/p'
```

everything up to the *last* occurrence:

```
sed -n 's/\(.*Exception\).*/\1/p'
```

Remove the `-n` and `p` if you want to preserve (unmodified) the lines that don't contain `Exception`.

Answer (score 2):

With your [favorite standard editor, ed](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html):

```
ed -s input <<< $'1,$s/Exception.*/Exception/\nw\nq'
```

This edits the input file `input` with a here-string list of commands, namely:

1. `1,$` -- on every line in the file (1 through the end `$`),
2. `s/Exception.*/Exception/` -- search and replace the string "Exception" followed by anything (`.*`) with just the word "Exception"
3. `w` -- write the file back to disk
4. `q` -- quit ed